# Is it possible to have multiple PHP-FPM?

Tags: php

I'm not sure if it is possible to have something like this:

`php55-fpm` and `php53-fpm` running at the same time

Comment: PHP is usually invoked by Apache or another webserver. What do you mean by having them _run at the same time_. Which version do you want your webserver to use? Or do you want to run two webservers?

Comment: `DON'T EVEN THINK OF USING THIS TAG!` did you even read?

Comment: I think this is possible if you will build them from the sources and will use different installation directories

Comment: Why is this question being downvoted?  This is a perfectly fine question

Comment: @kba Read up on how PHP-FPM works.  http://php-fpm.org/  It runs a daemon outside of the server.

Comment: @Brad Yes, it runs outside of the server, hence my question about which version he intends for the webserver to use. I don't understand why you think your statement contradicts what I'm asking.